# How to get only longitude and latitude from array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Noob questions but couldn't find a good answer,
I'm trying to only get the longitude and the latitude preferably in different strings. At the moment it works but it logs this:

```
Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 5,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitudeAccuracy": -1,
    "heading": -1,
    "latitude": 37.785834,
    "longitude": -122.406417,
    "speed": -1,
  },
  "timestamp": 1577094980806.544,
```

And this is the code:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import * as Location from "expo-location";

export default class GetLocation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    location: {},
    errorMessage: ""
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      longitude: [],
      latitude: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._getLocation();
  }

  _getLocation = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

    if (status !== "granted") {
      console.log("PERMISSION NOT GRANTED!");

      this.setState({
        errorMessage: "PERMISSION NOT GRANTED"
      });
    }
    const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
    this.setState({
      location
    });
    return location.JSON;
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.location);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{JSON.stringify(this.state.location)}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const View = styled.View``;
const Text = styled.Text`
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
`;
```

I want export the longitude and the latitude. I know the code is a bit messy. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you're not able to extract two properties from an object? o.O

Comment: @Andreas As I said, quite new, would love an advice. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is in "your" script. My advice? Research.

Comment: You can't swim without getting your certificate first. You'll simply drown. In other words: Learn the basics before you start messing around with code that's way too complicated for you to understand. Otherwise you'll just have to keep on asking more and more questions because you have no idea what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to parse the  JSON, is already an object:

```
 const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
    this.setState({
      location : {
        lat: location.coords.latitude,
        lon: location.coords.longitude
      }
    });
```

Render:

```
 <View>
    <Text>{this.state.location.lat} {this.state.location.lon} </Text>
  </View>
```

Comment: Replaced with this! Thanks, but how do I print now? :D

Comment: Edited, I suggest you to go through a basic react intro on the official doc, although

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to access this way:

```
console.log(this.state.location.coords.latitude);
```

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.location.coords')

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment),

Try this:

```js
let locationObj = {
    "coords": {
        "accuracy": 5,
        "altitude": 0,
        "altitudeAccuracy": -1,
        "heading": -1,
        "latitude": 37.785834,
        "longitude": -122.406417,
        "speed": -1,
    },
    "timestamp": 1577094980806.544,
}

const res = (({ latitude, longitude }) => ({ latitude, longitude }))(locationObj.coords);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @ZohirSalak OP is using `=>` function so I continued in the same way. If you have any better solution then you are welcome to post.